IF condition within Row Context measure in DAX
I need to calculate hours amount for unique routes in specific condition:
IF(8 - [Amount] <= 0, 0, [Amount])

Measure [Amount] is obtained from the row context measure SUMX, but applying IF statement to this measure it turns into a filter context and doesn't snow totals in table.
How can I solve this problem?
The code I wrote to receive temporary table:

The table I get (CNT is always 1 - that's correct:

The code I wrote to get my measure (the numbers obtained are correct):
Hours w/o visits = 
8 - SUMX(
        SUMMARIZE(
        FILTER(
            'GTM', ('GTM'[HOUR] >= 7 && 'GTM'[HOUR] <= 19)
            ),
            'GTM'[CALENDAR_DAY], 'GTM'[SALES_ROUTE_PO1], 'GTM'[HOUR], "CNT", 
            DISTINCTCOUNT('GTM'[HOUR])),
        [CNT]
        )

The table I receive in Power BI (Only positive numbers should remain, and negative numbers/zero should be counted as zero. Accordingly, the result is not correct. Here I need IF function.


Wouldn't it be possible to store your result in a variable (using VAR) within the same measure and then do a check before you return the result? Something like measureX = VAR XXX =  and then RETURN IF(XXX < 0, 0, XXX)?

What is the expected result? From what I see everywhere you should get 7 for Hours w/o Visits?
